# Динамическое добавление и удаление формы CKEditor

Tags: html, jquery, ckeditor

Есть код, которые добавляет/удаляет `input` с редактором `CKEditor`:

```js
$("#add").click(function(e) {
    $("#items").append('<div><input name="content[]" type="text" class="form-control ckeditor"/><button id="delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button></div>');
  })
  .on('click', function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace('content[]');
  });
$("body").on("click", "#delete", function(e) {
  $(this).parent("div").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div><button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Добавить поле</button></div>
<div id="items">
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что `CKEDITOR.replace()` срабатывает по индентификатору `name`, т. е. при попытке добавить еще один `input` с редактором, получаю ошибку `Uncaught The editor instance "content[]" is already attached to the provided element.`
Как применять эту функцию

```
.on('click', function () {
        CKEDITOR.replace('content[]');
    })
```

к каждому новому `input`?
Пробовал использовать [метод replaceAll](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replaceAll), редактор вообще не подгружается.

Comment: Вы вариант в вопросе даете? ну так пробуйте у себя

Comment: можете здесь дать рабочий код с `Ckeditor`?

Comment: такой что бы тут работу хоть и не правильную увидели

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Обновил вопрос

Comment: спасибо сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Во второй раз когда вы нажимаете на `Добавить поле` хотите получить второй редактор после первого? я правильно понял? или просто очистить первый?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan хочу получить второй редактор, вы правильно поняли!

Comment: И последний вопрос имя поля можно изменить? `content[]`

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan хм, я изначально думал собирать все данные по `content[]` в JSON, и класть в БД. Получается, менять нельзя. Но рассмотрю все варианты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял `ckeditor` не поддерживает `input array ([])`.

Для этого могу предложить вот такой вариант:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add").click(function(e) {
        //Append a new row of code to the "#items" div
        $("#items").append('<div><input name="content'+i+'" type="text" class="form-control ckeditor"/><button id="delete" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button></div>');
      })
      .on('click', function() {
            CKEDITOR.replace('content'+i);
            i++;
      });
    $("body").on("click", "#delete", function(e) {
      $(this).parent("div").remove();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<div><button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Добавить поле</button></div>
<div id="items">
</div>
```

Динамически добавить в имя каждого `input` число.